# errors using angular cli and intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, angular, angular-cli

I am just starting to play with angular CLI , I created a test project with

```
ng new quickstart-cli
```

And it has created all the initial folders , then I create the first component with :

```
ng g component hero-details
```

The problem comes when I trying to modify the hero-details.component.ts using intelliJ (I had install the angular plugin that supports angular 2 and typescript).

I have the following error .

[image]

It looks as is not recognize the tsconfig.json (1) file where this option is declare  and also I have a lot of error in the typescript compiler console (2) , It's trying to compile all the files of node , and I think it shouldn't do that.

[image]

I check out if intelliJ was not well configurated but I think everything is okey , I also try using the the option of use tsconfig.json but nothing changes.

[image]

If I select the the option of use tsconfig.json I have the following message from TypeScript Compiler

[image]

How i solved this ? Regards Roberto.

Comment: Does your application compile when you run `ng build`?

Comment: @Brocco yes , if I do that I have a successful build project .

Comment: You have an option there in the last screenshot that should be selected as "use tsconfig.json"

Comment: @JarodMoser okey thanks , I check that also as I said in the description , If I use that option the TypeScript Compiler says the following .  Warning : File was not compiled because there is no  a reference from tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your tsconfig.json with this snippet of code and let me know if it works :)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```